# Question about prime factorization of ideals in ring of integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Suppose that $p$ is a prime number, and $\mathcal{O}_K$ is the ring of integers of a number field $K$. Suppose we have $p\mathcal{O}_K=Q_1^{r_1}\cdots Q_n^{r_n}$, where the $Q_i$ are distinct nonzero prime ideals of $\mathcal{O}_K$ and $r_i\geq 1$. Suppose $P$ is a prime ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K$ such that $P\cap\mathbb{Z}=p\mathbb{Z}$. Then I'd like to show that $P$ is one of the $Q_i$.

My idea is that if I can show that $P$ contains $Q_1^{r_1}\cdots Q_n^{r_n}$, then it contains one of the $Q_i$ and so must be equal to that $Q_i$ since prime ideals are maximal in a Dedekind domain.

Now, $p\mathbb{Z}=p\mathcal{O}_K\cap\mathbb{Z}=Q_1^{r_1}\cdots Q_n^{r_n}\cap\mathbb{Z}=P\cap\mathbb{Z}$, but I'm not sure where to go from here to get what I want. What can I do?

Comment: If $p\in P$ then also $Q_1^{r_1}\dots Q_n^{r_n}=p\mathcal O_K\subset P$ by the properties of ideals.

Comment: Just a first thought, this seems equivalent to unique factorization of prime ideals in Dedekind domains. Can you use that theorem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that $p \in P \cap \mathbb Z$, so $p \in P$, so $p \mathcal O_K \subset P \mathcal O_K = P$.